# blue arrow in gmsmapview won't update whichever way i am facing

Tags: ios, google-maps

### I am using google map SDK 1.9.1. And i have to display blue arrow at direction which ever direction i am facing. but In new SDK i am not find any property to enable it. In old SDK it display that arrow but in new SDK it don't display that arrow

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - setup the google map
-(void) setupMap
{
     GMSMapView *mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] init];
                            mapView.delegate = self;
                            [mapView setMyLocationEnabled:YES];
                            [mapView.settings setCompassButton:YES];
                            [mapView.settings setMyLocationButton:YES];
                            [[self getGoogleMapView] addSubview:mapView];
}
```

[image]

**Edited**
hi after some research i found that direction is not display in ipod only but if you used google map in iphone it display direction arrow.

Comment: have you implemented "- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
" delegate method ?

Comment: @iOSNoob yes, i want same default location with arrow face the direction

Comment: No i haven't implement that method because this think handle by Google map framework it self in old SDK.

Comment: It should work, because Google didn't removed any features from new SDK, check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift

Comment: i also download and run this tutorial but still not able to get that arrow

Comment: You are running your application on simulator or device ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70545/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-iosnoob).

Answer (score 0):

The reason being that was a part of sensor parameter in the Direction API which is now Deprecated in all Google Maps Display.

Read the official [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). Scroll Down to  the bottom of page and you will see that.